# .NET program scan renderable text in Chart in .PDF - not for words but for values - Text Location features?

Tags: c#, .net, text-recognition

Hello I have a chart that I need to have the system review and give results...

Chart image located here....

[example chart .pdf http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/651/scorecardchartexample.gif/](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/651/scorecardchartexample.gif/)

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/651/scorecardchartexample.gif/

--Assume the chart is in .PDF and the text is renderable I.E. "highlight-able".

--Assume the chart is placed on the page exactly the same way and same position every time

--Assume the chart can change - that is to say, I need to be able to upload a 1000 of these charts all following the exact same format but with some alternate info from chart to chart.

--Assume VAST expertise in .NET - and little expertise in actual text interpretation.

--Assume expertise in interpreting .PDF that have editable fields...I am already doing this, this is limited to .PDF's I created and was able to place values on each field etc.

--Assume this chart is only deliverable in a single text renderable .PDF - that is to say - we interact with a website that creates this chart - this website has no API to interact with, we must print to PDF this chart from the webpage and that is all we can do...(government website)

Using a .NET system, I need to create a program...or incorporate an existing application into my .NET system, that will review this chart and will be able to tell what each "X" represents...that is to say an "X" one inch to the left or in the next row is an indicator of a different result (refer to chart)

I need the program to perform its search and return results based on the trigger of the .PDF document hitting a folder or whatever.  This part we can handle assuming we creating the program from scratch...otherwise we will be limited to interacting with an existing app as needed.

We are open to a variety of strategies.  Assuming such a class or object exists, we were thinking of reading text based on location in the document, like an X,Y sort of thing.  Another desireable route would be some sort of stringBuffer (assume C#) but will need to be able to navigate the chart gridlines and will need to count white spaces to accurately interpret the position of the "X"'s and what the "X" means based on its placement. 3rd option, something we are unware of.

If something exists and is tried and true, well that of course woould be best.  Then any tips on interfacing with it using .NET and C#.

Thank you all very much in advance Code Gawds!

Reel

Answer (score 0):

OK We found some software called ClearImage - it wasn't cheap but it is pretty neat.  It will analyze any image in the same fashion Adobe PDF analyzes a document to find form fields.  After clear image does that it gives you a list of "blobs" you then get to dictate what each blob means and give it a unique identifer.  This allows for auto value declaration based on "blob" placement in the image.

It also allows to sort of "finger print" an image so if the same image were to show up it could recognize it...in my case we have 3 different templates for the chart, and indeed each one will be different due to different charting, but ultimately each template has the same layout from multiples of the chart...this has helped in allowing our system to identfy what chart has been entered then after that first check, move on to anyalizing each blob.

Anyway, worth a look if anyone else should come across this question and is in need this type of function.  I didn't want to leave it unanswered.  I may update this as we learn more about it.  I know this isn't exactly a coding question but this type of task is coding intensive and if anyone was looking to perform the same task they may find their way here.  I will endeavor to update in the spirit of stackoverflow with comments relating to integration and objects etc. etc.

should anyone have more questions about this software in relation to coding you can ask here or post a new question, we will be happy to post our code (methods, classes objects etc.) we used (in C#) in terms of integrating it into our/your programs.